# linking static library to my project without naming it (VS2010)

Tags: c++, static-libraries, visual-studio-2010

This is the project structure:

```
main.c
lib\example.lib
lib\example.h
```

main.c:

```
#include "lib\example.h"
int main(void){ return example(); }
```

example.h

```
int example(void);
```

example.lib contains an implementation as follows `int example(void){return 4;}`

if i open the projec properties and navigate to input i can add the dependency by naming the lib file.

```
$(ProjectDir)\lib\example.lib
```

Is there a way of adding all the files in the lib directory without naming them?
All i can think of is editing the msbuild file to look for *.lib files and add them to the list before compiling.
I wonder if there is a built in way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wildcards inside of your makefile, but I think it's not good practice.

```
$(ProjectDir)\lib\*.lib
```

Comment: It's fine practice, but `*.lib` should be used as Johannes suggested.

Comment: Nice - i did not think about using wildcards there. :) I am glab i asked before editing the buildscript. Funny how i nearly answered it when asking the question :)

Comment: I wasn't sure, because I don't know buildscript systeme from vs, but I used it in makefiles so

Comment: This didn't really answer the question as to whether or not there was a built-in way to do this, as the OP already suggested he could edit the msbuild script. The wildcard method does not work within the VS project properties.

Comment: I just tested it, it works in VS2010-Express. It is built in enough for my purpose. If i "hacked" that property i may have ended up overloading build, injecting a generated list and recalling the buildtask. I may have formulated my qiestion poorly - but the answr is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @RyanJ well you'r right, I wanted to propose a solution, but I mentioned "makefile".
at Johannes, I'm glad that it helped you sorting this out.